# How do modern web browsers optimize the memory used by a tag?

Tags: html, dom, memory, webkit, gecko

I've read [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/) description of the internals of web browsers quite thoroughly, although it is a bit dated.

According to this description, each HTML element is represented internally by three objects - the document tag, its renderer (usually one per tag), and a css style context. Various optimizations are described for the css style context, which would be very large in a naive implementation (perhaps several kilobytes.)

However, these optimizations still don't seem sufficient - modern browsers now handle very large documents (tens of thousands of lines) with high speed & low memory usage. And some elements (such as `<br>`) don't appear to require per-instance renderers or styles. Also, long program listings on github appear to use a three table cells with nested elements per line, so there must be some nifty optimizations under the hood.

So, the question: what other memory optimizations are used to represent HTML elements in modern browser engines?

The question is only about memory optimizations that have been actually implemented, and only about element representation, not javascript or any other aspect of a browser, so I suspect there are just a handful of clever techniques.

Here's a stab at some of the optimizations I could think of:

1. The tag (e.g. `<span>`): Intern the names. Use internally linked lists of elements (forward and back pointers) to avoid the overhead of external lists.
2. Renderers: a) Since renderers implement the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) perhaps a way of eliminating memory usage when margins/borders/paddings are zero? Or when they are identical across boxes? b) Eliminating separate renderers for simple objects like `<br>`?
3. CSS Styles: This has been written about in the document referenced at the start of this post: a) Divide the styles into separate structures that can be individually shared or inherited when no overriding declarations exist. b) What about the overhead of having several structures per element? Just the pointer space alone would add up - e.g. if there are say 10 structures (e.g. font styles, table styles, border styles, etc.) per element, even if these are shared that means 10 pointers per element - 80 bytes on a 64 bit system.)

Comment: This is way too broad, as it's essentially calling for a theoretically infinite list of things. Maybe if you could break it down to a specific example of a document being used efficiently by browser X...

Comment: See my clarification. It isn't broad at all. Implementors of browsers will know the data structures and the memory optimizations they've used cold, since they've been worked on intensively.